# Meeting room calendars missing - Office 365 API

Tags: python, office365, office365api

I am trying to get the list of all calendars for a user. This user has delegate permissions to view the calendar of all the meeting rooms (resources). If I log into the user's account and I am able to see the meeting room calendars in the "Other Calendars" section. I also created my own calendar called "Test" in the "Other Calendars" section.

When I get all the calendar groups first and then iterate through the calendar group list and get the calendars, the list for "Other Calendars" only has "Test" calendar.

Not sure why this is the case. The user is a global administrator as well.

```
def get_access_info_from_authcode(auth_code, redirect_uri):

    post_data = { 'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': auth_code,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'scope': ' '.join(str(i) for i in scopes),
            'client_id': client_registration.client_id(),
            'client_secret': client_registration.client_secret()
          }

    r = requests.post(access_token_url, data = post_data, verify = verifySSL)

    try:
        return r.json()
    except:
        return 'Error retrieving token: {0} - {1}'.format(r.status_code, r.text)

def get_access_token_from_refresh_token(refresh_token, resource_id):
    post_data = { 'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
                  'client_id' : client_registration.client_id(),
                  'client_secret' : client_registration.client_secret(),
                  'refresh_token' : refresh_token,
                  'resource' : resource_id }

    r = requests.post(access_token_url, data = post_data, verify = verifySSL)

    # Return the token as a JSON object
    return r.json()
def get_calendars_from_calendar_groups(calendar_endpoint, token, calendar_groups):
    results = []
    for group_id in calendar_groups:
        get_calendars = '{0}/me/calendargroups/{1}/calendars'.format(calendar_endpoint, group_id)
        r = make_api_call('GET', get_calendars, token)

        if (r.status_code == requests.codes.unauthorized):
            logger.debug('Response Headers: {0}'.format(r.headers))
            logger.debug('Response: {0}'.format(r.json()))
            results.append(None)
        results.append(r.json())
    return results
def get_calendars(calendar_endpoint, token, parameters=None):
    if (not parameters is None):
        logger.debug('  parameters: {0}'.format(parameters))

    get_calendars = '{0}/me/calendars'.format(calendar_endpoint)    
    if (not parameters is None):
        get_calendars = '{0}{1}'.format(get_calendars, parameters)
    r = make_api_call('GET', get_calendars, token)
    if(r.status_code == requests.codes.unauthorized):
        logger.debug('Unauthorized request. Leaving get_calendars.')
        return None
    return r.json()
```

Logic + Code:
Step 1) Get the authorization URL:

```
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
authorize_url = '{0}{1}'.format(authority, '/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&response_type=code&state={2}&prompt=consent')
```

Step 2) Opening the URL takes us to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common where I login as the user:
[image]

Step 3) This redirects back to my localhost then the following:

```
discovery_result = exchoauth.get_access_info_from_authcode(auth_code, Office365.redirect_uri)

refresh_token = discovery_result['refresh_token']

client_id = client_registration.client_id()
client_secret = client_registration.client_secret()

access_token_json = exchoauth.get_access_token_from_refresh_token(refresh_token, Office365.resource_id)

access_token = access_token_json['access_token']


calendar_groups_json = exchoauth.get_calendar_groups(Office365.api_endpoint, access_token)
            cal_groups = {}

if calendar_groups_json is not None:
    for entry in calendar_groups_json['value']:
        cal_group_id = entry['Id']
        cal_group_name = entry['Name']
        cal_groups[cal_group_id] = cal_group_name

    calendars_json_list = exchoauth.get_calendars_from_calendar_groups(Office365.api_endpoint,
                    access_token, cal_groups)

    for calendars_json in calendars_json_list:
        if calendars_json is not None:
            for ent in calendars_json['value']:
                cal_id = ent['Id']
                cal_name = ent['Name']
                calendar_ids[cal_id] = cal_name
```

Let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 0):

The delegate-token which request with the **Auth code grant flow** only able to get the calendars of sign-in user.

If you want to the get the events from the specific room, you can use the app-only token request with **client credential flow**.

[Here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) is an helpful link for your reference.

Comment: I am not yet trying to get the events for the specific room. I am just trying to list all the meeting room calendars (which the user is able to see in their calendars list) to be returned when I call the API (/me/calendargroups/{id}/calendars).
http://picresize.com/images/rsz_screenshot_from_2016-08-12_06-31-05.png

In this screenshot you will see 4 calendars, Strongbad + Furnace are meeting room calendars, which this user has delegate permissions. When I make the API call, it only returns Calendars, Test as results.

Comment: At present, the Office 365 REST is not able list the the calendars which the user has delegate.  If you want the Office 365 REST to support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).